# My video modal is showing blank on load page, how do I correct it?

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks for taking the time of reading this post. My modal is showing blank when I load my page, all the modals showing when clicking are working perfectly, my script isn't working as I intended.

My HTML

```
       <a title="Video promocional Salsas Harvest Of Love" data-toggle="modal" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nxLtwE0Rr0k?rel=0?autoplay=1" data-target="#videoModal3" class="text-color video-modal"><i class="ti-control-play bg-gradient hover-shadow btn-play mr-2"></i><span>Ver video</span></a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content border-0 rounded-0">
              <iframe width="560" height="315" src="" id="video3" frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Declared Script in bottom of body

```
<script>
  $('#videoModal3').modal('show');
</script>
```

Js declared in outside .js file (which works on all other modals)

```
$('#videoModal3').on('hide.bs.modal',function(e){$("#video3").attr('src',$videoSrc);})
```